# Detecting Bots Who are sending Spam Mails via Webmail

Tags: botnet, email-spoofing, anomaly-detection, spam

I am working on spam Detection done by botnets.

**Some Information**

Recently,I came through a techique to detect the spammer in my network which is based on the anamolous amount of MX queries,outbound SMTP connections ,an internal host/bot generates(Which is rare in maximum cases,as legitimate/internal hosts talk to internal mail server,not directly to destination mail server).

However,if my network blocks oubound smtp,bots won't be able to spam.

On the contrary,bots also use web-mail services(through http like gmail,hotmail,which is open in any network) and send spam mails.

**Query**

In this scenario,how will it be possible for me to detect the spamming activity of bot(as most of the webmail traffic is encrypted) or how do i detect the bots in my network that are sending spam mails using extrenal webmail services(gmail,hotmail,etc.).

Thanks

Comment: Even though encrypted, you can see the domain name. Perhaps you could detect a client connecting to multiple mail services in a very short amount of time? Best to confirm by looking  at what's running on the client, if possible.

Comment: Does server logs are not enough for that? You need to quantify the amount of mails sent by account per time and which are the targeted domains... you may get an idea which accounts have been compromised.

Comment: @NeilSmithline ,i was thinking this technique might fail ,because how can we be always sure that domain name in the request is mail-service,unless it somes popular like gmail,hotmail

Comment: @user10012 yes, it will only work for known mail domains. I think what you're asking is likely impossible and you'll have to settle for some weak heuristics

Comment: @NeilSmithline,then which heuristics can be chosen including the one you mentioned?. Machine learning techniques can be applied if i am able to see SMTP traffic,however as data are encrypted,all are same(tcp/http/tls) ,then distinguish between ham and spam is a far case.

Comment: I really am not sure, that's why I didn't write an answer. Sorry

Comment: [Also posted on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/778347/111679).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W. i have removed this question from serverfault.